# How to force Air app html-based to open with admin privileges?

Tags: air

I need the app open with admin privileges always in mac, windows e ubuntu. Is there a way to specify this in the XML description file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed this permission to write to the database. I discovered that it is right to point to the temporary directory that is created in the user system folder, instead of pointing to the installation folder.

Comment: What if your installation comes with prepopulted database, how can you move it to user system folder and then open it ? Please ellaborate on your solution. Thank you

Comment: You will need to create the database with js trough the air API. Here is the doc: http://goo.gl/PY4uB7